# Does using terminal-based text browsers provide significant improvements in browsing speed?

Tags: command-line, browser, elinks, lynx

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I know two methods to access the web-pages through terminal. They are `lynx` and  `elinks`. When I tried to use them to access web-pages from terminal, I didn't seem to get any improvements on browsing speed. I am not sure whether it's just normal or my Internet speed is slow.

So what is the best way to access the web-page? Through terminal browsers or GUI browsers?
And what are the benefits and limitations of using text based terminal browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course using a text browser will increase your browsing speed. It makes sense because text browsers don't have image, flash and other graphics objects so they don't load on them.

> What is the best way to access web-page?

It depends on the situation. In normal scenario, Using a traditional graphical browser is best. But if you have very low speed Internet connection or a limit on monthly usage, you may want to cut your usage and hence may want to use text browser.

### Benefits and Limitations

The benefits are high speed browsing, less data usage.

The Limitations are you can't see the image, sometimes it is essential such as for capcha, can't play video and miss usability or productivity a bit. Also you will lack using mouse which is sometimes very inconvenient for inexperience users

Comment: Good explanation

Comment: looking for elinks and lynx